# How to export Table to CSV along with column names in PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, export-to-csv

I am trying to export the users table into CSV format using PHPMYADMIN but i get only the records and not the coloumn names. So How to do that? I am trying to import a CSV but it needs coloumn names so i want to have a csv that has column names !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

where you download table into csv

just click on "put column name in the first row. check below image

[image]

Comment: Thanks buddy i missed to see that